# odoo 11, How to generate report in xls format?

Tags: xml, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter, odoo-11

I would like to create a report in xls format in odoo11. I have a set of results in python,I want to print the report in excel sheet.

Comment: You can use the `Excel Report Engine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **TRY BELOW CODE**
- Python code:-

  ```
  from odoo import models
  class PartnerXlsx(models.AbstractModel):
      _name = 'report.report_xlsx.partner_xlsx'
      _inherit = 'report.report_xlsx.abstract'

  def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
      for obj in partners:
          sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Report')
          bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
          sheet.write(0, 0, obj.name, bold)
  ```
- XML code:-

  `<report
      id="partner_xlsx"
      model="res.partner"
      string="Print to XLSX"
      report_type="xlsx"
      name="report_xlsx.partner_xlsx"
      file="res_partner"
      attachment_use="False"
  />`

Comment: Hello, i have same problem. Is that possible, don't use report tag then print excel report from button? Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868643/how-to-call-a-xlsx-report-from-button-in-odoo

Comment: Hello @С.Дэлгэрцэцэг i can't find your link.